# User seems to be copying other users' answers

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I noticed that user [Parzival](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20325/parzival) recently posted answers to several questiosn ([here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29788/the-recursive-reflection-of-this-rebus-may-be-too-revealing/29808#29808), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/answer-questions/29813#29813), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/what-am-i-a-rebus/29811#29811), and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29737/a-puzzling-rebus-puzzle/29812#29812)). Each of their answers was the exact copy of a highly upvoted answer. The last link even had a user point out that Parzival might be copying previous answers.

(Note: I'm just using Parzival as a recent example; I have seen other users do similar things.)

### Request

Should there be a flag for answers that are duplicates of other answers that other users have posted previously?

Comment: What would you flag for? None of his answers seem copied word-for-word, only the one-word answer happens to be the same. That's what happens on a site like this, especially with the community's insistence on spoiler tags.

Comment: And there's another question along these lines around here somewhere.

Comment: Ah, There it is